# Quickly copy one file thousands of times

Tags: bash, performance

For performance testing I need to make thousands of copies of a single file. Is there a faster way to do that with a bash script than `cp` in a `for` loop? I know tools exist for creating one copy of thousands of files (rsync, etc.), but is there a tool that exploits the fact that the source file is always the same to speed up the process?

Comment: Look up GNU Parallel

Comment: Parallel is no more efficient than a `for` loop, just syntactically more concise.

Comment: I'd expect that writing to the disk is what's gonna slow things down.

Comment: @TomFenech good point

Comment: @TomFenech Yep, there's no way around that, but since the file is small (9k) I was hoping to avoid having `cp` read it from disk thousands of times.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if when you access a file several times in a row it ends up being cached at some level anyway. Whereas when you're writing it to thousands of separate destinations, that's what's going to cost you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @chepner's ideas...

This takes 6.3 seconds (8 at a time) to make 10,000 copies:

```
parallel -N 8 'cat source.txt | tee copy{1}.txt copy{2}.txt copy{3}.txt copy{4}.txt copy{5}.txt copy{6}.txt copy{7}.txt copy{8}.txt ' ::: {1..10000}
```

This takes 19 seconds (one at a time):

```
for i in {1..10000}; do cp source.txt copy${i}.txt; done
```

This takes 5 seconds (10 at a time):

```
time parallel -N 10 'cat source.txt | tee copy{1}.txt copy{2}.txt copy{3}.txt copy{4}.txt copy{5}.txt copy{6}.txt copy{7}.txt copy{8}.txt copy{9}.txt copy{10}.txt' ::: {1..10000}
```

Note that I am running on an SSD, results may be worse with spinning disks.

Comment: Doesn't `parallel` have a way to run the command with as many arguments as possible, instead of having to hard-code a fixed number of arguments?

Comment: @chepner Yes, but I am struggling to work out how to pick them all up and prefix them individually with `copy` and postfix them with `.txt` :-)

Comment: Maybe @OleTange will have to help me out - yet again!

Answer (score 2):

You might try `tee`. For example,

```
cat source.txt | tee copy1.txt copy2.txt copy3.txt > copy4.txt
```

It's probably not significantly faster than running multiple copies of `cp`, but there is slightly less process startup overhead. (Here, running `tee` once instead of `cp` 4 times.)

Comment: I guess that you could use `copy{0001..1000}.txt` or something to simplify the naming, too.

Comment: `thousands of copies` is gonna be prettttty long using this.  maybe `cat source.txt | tee copy{1..1000).txt`

Comment: Depending on the length of each copy's filename, you'll probably still have to break this into several rounds, since a command line with thousands of arguments will probably be too long (which is actually something that `parallel` *could* help with).

Comment: Command line limits on modern systems are *enormous*. `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` will show them. `echo copy{1..10000}.txt | wc -c` is `128894` and `xargs` on my CentOS 6 machine lists `Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2615106`.

Comment: `echo`, as a shell built-in, isn't subject to the limit. Good to know that `xargs` provides a way to see what the limit on the local system is.

Answer (score 0):

I think all methods based on standard coreutils (cp, tee, etc...) will have - more or less - the same performances. They also have tens of different options you don't really need and each of them uses system resources.

If you need something really fast you can code your `pcopy` on your own. It's not very complicated and you can use copy.c (used by cp and other std coreutils programs) as starting point.

I would use the following approach:

1. read the source file once and keep it in memory (assuming you can)
2. start a configurable number of threads
3. each thread to write the same copy of the source file to disk (either synch O_DIRECT with aligned blocks or Asynch IO)

I think that a `pcopy` coded this way can be significantly faster than std coreutils.

Answer (score 0):

Copy file a to b1 .. b1000

```
echo b{1..1000}  | xargs -n 1 cp a
```